# Systematic way to find all automorphisms of a (particular) symmetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Is there a systematic way (e.g., an algorithm) to find all automorphisms of an arbitrary symmetric group $S_n$?

If not, can we simplify this question and ask again? That is, can there be some kind of properties which if n satisfies, then a systematic way to find all automorphisms of $S_n$ does exist?

(This question is asked as a generalization of one of my homework.)

Comment: Apart from $n=6$, all automorphism of $S_n$ are inner automorphisms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you! I haven't learned that fact. Could you please give a hint to prove that fact?

Comment: An automorphism maps a conjugacy class to a conjugacy class. A conjugacy class in $S_n$ is a set of elements of the same cycle type. Consider the image of the conjugacy class of transpositions.

Comment: @RobertChamberlain Thank you! I shall think about it more.

Answer (score 1):

Touching on what Lord Shark the Unknown said, $S_6$ is the only symmetric group with nontrivial outer automorphism group, which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}/2\Bbb{Z}.$ The map which provides this is making the appropriate map that sends
$$(ab)\mapsto (cd)(ef)(gh).$$
The map is entirely defined by how it is defined on these transpositions, since $S_n$ is generated by its transpositions.

See more about it here: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_groups_on_finite_sets_are_complete

Comment: @DerekHolt, fixed. I thought I had written the final pair.